# Regular expression to match word pairs joined with colons

Tags: regex

I don't know regular expression at all. Can anybody help me with one very simple regular expression which is,

extracting '**word:word**' from a sentence. e.g "Java Tutorial **Format:Pdf** With **Location:Tokyo** Javascript"?

- Little modification:
  the first 'word' is from a list but second is anything. "word1 in [ABC, FGR, HTY]"
- guys situation demands a little more
  modification.
  The matching form can be "word11:word12 word13 .. " till the next "word21: ... " .

things are becoming complex with sec.....i have to learn reg ex :(

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
\w+:\w+
```

Explanation:
`\w` - single char which is either a letter(uppercase or lowercase), digit or a _.
`\w+` - one or more of above char..basically a word

so `\w+:\w+` 
would match a pair of words separated by a colon.

Answer (score 2):

Try `\b(\S+?):(\S+?)\b`. Group 1 will capture "Format" and group 2, "Pdf".

A working example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {
    var re = /\b(\S+?):(\S+?)\b/g; // without 'g' matches only the first
    var text = "Java Tutorial Format:Pdf With Location:Tokyo  Javascript";

    var match = null;
    while ( (match = re.exec(text)) != null) {
        alert(match[1] + " -- " + match[2]);
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="test();">

</body>
</html>
```

A good reference for regexes is https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: +1 for the complete example, but -1 for a regex that's too complicated for its own good. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet :

```
 
$str=" this is pavun:kumar hello world bk:systesm" ;
if ( preg_match_all  ( '/(\w+\:\w+)/',$str ,$val ) )
 {
 print_r ( $val ) ;
 }
 else
 {
 print "Not matched \n";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Continuing Jaú's function with your additional requirement:

```
function test() {
    var words = ['Format', 'Location', 'Size'],
            text = "Java Tutorial Format:Pdf With Location:Tokyo Language:Javascript", 
            match = null;
    var re = new RegExp( '(' + words.join('|') + '):(\\w+)', 'g');
    while ( (match = re.exec(text)) != null) {
        alert(match[1] + " = " + match[2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently solving that problem in my nodejs app and found that this is, what I guess, suitable for colon-paired wordings:

```
([\w]+:)("(([^"])*)"|'(([^'])*)'|(([^\s])*))
```

It also matches quoted value. like `a:"b" c:'d e' f:g`

Example coding in es6:

```
const regex = /([\w]+:)("(([^"])*)"|'(([^'])*)'|(([^\s])*))/g;
const str = `category:"live casino" gsp:S1aik-UBnl aa:"b" c:'d e' f:g`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
   // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
   if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
      regex.lastIndex++;
   }

   // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
   m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
      console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
   });
}
```

Example coding in PHP

```
$re = '/([\w]+:)("(([^"])*)"|\'(([^\'])*)\'|(([^\s])*))/';
$str = 'category:"live casino" gsp:S1aik-UBnl aa:"b" c:\'d e\' f:g';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

You can check/test your regex expressions using this online tool: https://regex101.com

Btw, if not deleted by regex101.com, you can browse that example coding [here](https://regex101.com/r/mBcD1u/2)

Answer (score -1):

here's the non regex way, in your favourite language, split on white spaces, go through the element, check for ":" , print them if found. Eg Python

```
>>> s="Java Tutorial Format:Pdf With Location:Tokyo Javascript"
>>> for i in s.split():
...     if ":" in i:
...         print i
...
Format:Pdf
Location:Tokyo
```

You can do further checks to make sure its really "someword:someword" by splitting again on ":" and checking if there are 2 elements in the splitted list. eg

```
>>> for i in s.split():
...     if ":" in i:
...         a=i.split(":")
...         if len(a) == 2:
...             print i
...
Format:Pdf
Location:Tokyo
```

Answer (score -2):

```
([^:]+):(.+)
```

Meaning: (everything except : one or more times), :, (any character one ore more time)

You'll find good manuals on the net... Maybe it's time for you to learn...

Comment: Does not work: take this simple input: "ab cd:ef gh" you'll match 'ab cd' and 'ef gh' instead of 'cd' and 'ef'

Comment: This regexp is very wrong, you might make good use of the manuals too.

Comment: Didn't understand that, sorry. But the regexp works, and you just have to adjust it the following way: ([^:\s]+):([^\s]+)