# JAVA REGEX extract round colon "123:32:21"

Tags: java, regex

Here's the string format I'm working with: `123:23:21`

The three separate numbers could range from 1 to 99999, it's essentially a key to represent a set of data.

I need to extract each of the separate numbers

- The first before the colon "123"
- The second between the first colon "32" and last colon
- The third after the last colon "21"

I've found a few answers (below), but don't provide enough info for a complete amateur to do what I need too.

- [Regular expression to match word pairs joined with colons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370588/regular-expression-to-match-word-pairs-joined-with-colons)
- [Regex to find a string after the last colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354662/regex-to-find-a-string-after-the-last-colon)
- [Regex: Question mark and colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530862/regex-question-mark-and-colon)

These are completely wrong but I've tried variations of `^\w+:$`, `^:\w+:$`, `^:\w+$`.

Can anyone give me a heads up as to how to implement this in Java? Could be regex or substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java, u can use split method of String or can use `Scanner.useDelimiter(pattern)`

Ex-

```
String str = "123:23:21";
String[] nums = str.split(":");

num[0] - 123, num[1] = 23, num[2] = 21 //output
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `^` and `$`, as these, respectively, indicate the start and end of the string.

Try just `\w+` (the `:` can be omitted since `\w` doesn't include `:`, and wouldn't work too well at the start and end of the string, unless you make it optional).

Then you'll use [`Matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) to find each occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to match the number from `1 - 99999` separated by colon.

```
String input = "text 123:23:99999 number";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\D|^)([1-9][0-9]{0,4}):([1-9][0-9]{0,4}):([1-9][0-9]{0,4})(?:\\D|$)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `split()` -

```
String string = "123:23:21";
String[] parts = string.split(":");
for(String p:parts){
    System.out.println(p);
}
/* OUTPUT */
123
23
21
```

Answer (score 0):

For the string 123:32:21
You can use `[^:]+:` to get 123: and `:[^:]+:` to get :32: and `:[^:]+` to get :21 and the remove the `:` from the string

A nice explanation for regex is give in 
http://www.beedub.com/book/2nd/regexp.doc.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all \w matches word chatacters. For only numbers you need \d. You can extract all three numbers with one regexp using matching groups.

```
(\d+)\:(\d+)\:(\d+)
```

Dont forget to write double backslashes if you init your Pattern. From a Matcher which is created by your Pattern you then get the group data. Groups are the (  ) areas from your regexp.

You could improve this by ^   and  $  like you already did to force line boundaries.